# DataTable Select parameterized like SQL Select where x = @param

Tags: sql, select, parameters, datatable, where-clause

What is the query syntax from getting the rows of a DataTable that is equivalent of this SQL Query?

```
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(System.String.Format("Data Source={0}", fpath));

        cnn.Open();
        DataTable primaryfeed = new DataTable();

        using (SQLiteTransaction dbTrans = cnn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            {

                string command = System.String.Format("SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM AccountDataBase WHERE ID = @ID");

                SQLiteParameter param1 = new SQLiteParameter();

                param1.ParameterName = "@ID";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

                cmd.CommandText = command;

                for (int i = 0; i < selectedIDs.Length; i++)
                {

                    param1.Value = selectedIDs[i];

                    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    primaryfeed.Load(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
        cnn.Close();
```

So I have a DataTable and a stringarray of IDs. What is the command to get all rows from the DataTable that have the ID values from the array the quickest way possible?

Is it much slower than the equivalent SQL Query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myTable` has a column named `ID`, then you do:

```
var foundRows = myTable.Select("ID IN (1, 12, 14, 10)");
```

Comment: thx for the answer
it has an ID column but
 the most important part of the question is that this ID array can range from a few thousand to a few tenthousand. That's why I can't simply concetanate a string like that.
or do you think it would work properly if I append a 4800 ID string inside that Select bracket?